# .htaccess url rewrite to room/Blabla

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a question, I'm trying to edit my url using htaccess and its somehow broken...
My url: url.com/room.php?videoID=Blabla
The url I want: url.com/room/Blabla

I wrote something which actually worked, but considered file.php as a videoID and returned error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^es/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ room.php?roomID=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ room.php?roomID=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^room/([^/]*)$ /room.php?videoID=$1 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL: `url.com/room/Blabla`